# Decoding text in PDF file using PDFSharp using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, pdf, pdfsharp

I'm trying to extract text from a PDF using the [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) Libraries in VisualBasic.Net

Below is my code loading an invoice generated by Crystal Reports

```
Dim SourceFileName As String = "D:\vbpROJECTS\firstpagetest.pdf"
Dim Inputdocument As PdfDocument = PdfReader.Open(SourceFileName, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import)
Dim TextExtract As String

TextExtract =Inputdocument.Pages(0).Contents.Elements.GetDictionary(0).Stream.ToString
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox1.Text = TextExtract
```

This will load the text into a textbox but it seems to be encoded. Using XPDFTools pdftotext.exe confirms that its not encrypted because its able to extract all of the text into a readable format. iTextSharp also has no issue reading the text from this document.

Instead I get the below it's just a partial BT ET snip-it .

`**BT**
1 0 0 -1 580 2168 Tm
/9 143 Tf
(XF22) Tj
[(G)14(8=V2$M;G\\N$)(Y)77(GS)] TJ
0 -180 **Td**
(ST8H$UT=VS$W=VVH2) **Tj**
[(G)14(8HV$XFYY)] TJ
0 -180 Td
(SZ=*FH) Tj
0 -180 Td
([F) Tj
**ET**`

And some more.

Td
(]#.D^%X.B%=@B%7@>D%?=6696%.7%.M9%?5:-M=69:%7@%?=D89@.%7O%) Tj
-999 -147 Td
(.MF6%F@`7F-9%F@%O5>>A%TF6a%?=6696%7@%:9-9F?.%7O%N77B6A%C5=@.F.F96%856.%;9%) Tj
0 -147 Td
(-7@OF:89B%=.%.F89%7O%:9-9F?.A%'@D%BF6-:9?=@-F96%-=@@7.%;9%=--9?.9B%=O.9:%) Tj
0 -147 Td
(B9>F`9:D%5@>966%:9-7:B9B%7@%.M9%F@`7F-9%=.%.F89%7O%:9-9F?.A%#>9=69%:9O9:%.7%) Tj
0 -147 Td
(___A-=@7@A-7Ab=%O7:%75:%O5>>%.9:86%=@B%-7@BF.F7@6) Tj

I have read through chapter 9 of
http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Its talking about CMap and WinAnsi Text encoding. I read through it over and over but just cannot understand why I can't find text in the PDF. I also tried to find an online WinAnsiDecoder but it does not seem to exist, also win ansi encoding seems to be pretty much the same as ASCII. and the below does not look like ASCII.

Off-coarse if I create a dummy Word Document with a couple of pictures and a few lines of text then save as PDF and load it with the above code I get some text which can read using a parser that will eliminate the PDF "tags" the ISO32000 PDF reference then also makes sense.

Why am I getting text that reads "ST8H$UT=VS$W=VVH2" ?

FYI,I don't wan to use iTextsharp.

Comment: If you really *have read through chapter 9* of ISO 32000-1 *over and over*, how can you have missed the information that the font details, in particular the encoding used for each font, is defined in the page (or XObject or pattern or...) resources? *FYI,I don't wan to use iTextsharp* - that's ok, the name "iTextSharp" anyways is in the process of being phased out.

Comment: That looks a bit like problems i was having when trying to read PDF files that were created using the msxps printer driver - Open the PDF in Adobe's acrobat reader, click on the file menu and choose Properties. I can't remember which property shows it, but i think it's either the Application property or  the PDF producer property, but if you see "msxps" anywhere, that is possibly your problem. msxps is a poor PDF creator and can produce broken PDFs.

Comment: Although you can see it in Acrobat reader, you're just seeing a render of the file. Each character is something like a rendered image, but when you try to, say copy and paste, because the font information is broken, the clipboard, and all PDF text extractors just get garbage. I found a workaround where you render the PDF as a bitmap and run the bitmap through an OCR reader like  tesseract. OCR isn't perfect

Comment: So it may be better to find a different way of creating your PDF files

Comment: mkl , how does your first sentence contribute to the problem? It doesnt why did you even awnser ?, not helpfull at all.  David Wilson, thanks will look into the OCR part I however I dont think the PDF is rendered to an image and that OCR is needed. The text is there and other PDF to text readers can rewad the text also iTextSharp is able to extract the text sucessfully.

Comment: @MartinViljoenTheTechTinkerT can you post a link to the PDF file so we can download and take a look at it?

Comment: Hi , The original document is a customer invoice so i created a new PDF with crystal reports and uploaded using google drive. It seems its only crystal reports that creates this strange encoding. the Link :https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_P8sSWRxk6rF5lAQoHNHip_XaN43AoWs?usp=sharing when I created this I noticed a resemblance

I pasted the below into 2 columns Col1 in clear text and then next to it
DAUT001 .*/$%%&
DBAD001 .8*.%%&
DBAH001 .8*7%%&
DBAH002 .8*7%%'
DBAN001 .8*;%%&

From the above it looks like 
D = .
A = *
U = /
T= $
0=%
1=&